# C++ soci inserting row from one table into another with same structure

Tags: c++, database, soci

I have two tables in different databases but their structure is identical. It is possible that one or more columns contain "null" values. I found the following

http://soci.sourceforge.net/doc/3.2/exchange.html (See indicators)

How do I apply this to several columns? I also tried to solve this by using a rowset:

```
 soci::rowset<soci::row> rs = myDatabase->prepare << select;
```

However I dont know how to enter this rowset into the other database and furthermore I dont know if this works when i need to work with a lot of rows. Until now i solved copying a lot of data by using statements:

```
soci::statement st = (myDatabase->prepare << select);
st.execute();

while (st.fetch()) {
    // For each row...
}
```

I appreciate any help